# Como faço a concatenação de duas variaveis formar uma variavel sequencial

Tags: php, variáveis

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
session_start();
$var_quant = $_SESSION['quantvend'];
$var_varejo_atacado = $_GET['varejo-atacado'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("edutricot");


for($i = 1; $i<=$var_quant ; $i++){
    $var_nome{$i} = $_GET['txtcod'.$i];
    $var_quantvend{$i} = $_GET['txtquant'.$i];
    $var_varejo_atacado = $_GET['varejo-atacado'];
    echo $var_varejo_atacado;
    echo $var_nome{$i};
    echo $var_quantvend{$i};
    echo "<br>";

    $query = "SELECT $var_varejo_atacado FROM estoque where nome = $var_nome.$i";
    $dados = mysql_query($query,$con);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($dados,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $var_valor{$i} = $row["$var_varejo_atacado"];
        $_GLOBALS['valor'.$i] = $var_valor{$i};

    }


    $_GLOBALS['prodquant'.$i] = $var_quantvend{$i};
    $var_valor{$i} = $_GLOBALS['valor'.$i];
}
?>
```

Sou novo em mexer com php e precisava que alguém me explica-se como eu consigo concatenar duas variáveis para colocar na consulta do MySql.

```
$query = "SELECT $var_varejo_atacado FROM estoque where nome = $var_nome.$i";
```

Estou tentando concatenar usando o . mas sempre da erro, teria alguma forma de fazer essa concatenaçao?

```
$var_nome{$i} = $_GET['txtcod'.$i];
```

esta é a linha em que estou tentando pegar a informação, mas percebi que o `$var_nome{$i}` não esta concatenando da forma que eu esperava, não esta criando por exemplo `$var_nome1`, `$var_nome2` etc.

Comment: Acho que você deveria rever o código e utilizar array ao invés de continuar com a linha de raciocínio de usar variáveis sequenciais, tanto no HTML quanto no PHP.

Comment: Use [array](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Primeira coisa, melhor rever o codigo com variaveis sequenciais, há formas melhores para trabalhar sua aplicação. Mas como ja estamos aqui.
Talvez seja melhor voce usar array e fazer um "where in" na consulta

```
$array = [];    
for() {
       $array[] = $var_nome.$i       
    }
```

depois vcs usa o fetch da query fora do for, tem mto processamento ai

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $var_varejo_atacado WHERE nome IN (".implode(',',$array).")"; 
$dados = mysql_query($query,$con);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($dados,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $var_valor{$i} = $row["$var_varejo_atacado"];
        $_GLOBALS['valor'.$i] = $var_valor{$i};

    }
```